# Implementing Binary Tree in Java with Generic Comparable<T> data?

Tags: java, generics, binary-tree, comparable

**Q:** In my implementation of a binary tree below, why does the compiler choke at

`if (data.compareTo(this.data) <= 0)`,

producing

`Error: incompatible types: java.lang.Comparable<T> cannot be converted to T`?

Both `data` and `this.data` are of type `Comparable<T>` and should be able to use or be an argument to the compareTo() method...right? Well, clearly not. But I really don't understand why. Generics are still baffling me.

```
public class MyBinaryTreeNodeG<T>{
  Comparable<T> data;
  MyBinaryTreeNodeG<T> parent;
  MyBinaryTreeNodeG<T> left;
  MyBinaryTreeNodeG<T> right;

  public MyBinaryTreeNodeG(Comparable<T> data){
   this.data = data; 
  }

  public MyBinaryTreeNodeG<T> addChild(Comparable<T> data){
    if (data.compareTo(this.data) <= 0) { //this is the line on which the compiler chockes
    //check if left tree node is null. If so, add. Otherwise, recurse.
    } else {
    //same for the right tree node
    return null;
  }
```

The following is a clip from a more standard implementation of a binary tree. This compiles fine. But I still fail to see why this is a "better" (according to compiler) implementation than mine above.

```
public class MyBinaryTreeNodeG<T extends Comparable<T>>{
  T data;
  MyBinaryTreeNodeG<T> parent;
  MyBinaryTreeNodeG<T> left;
  MyBinaryTreeNodeG<T> right;

  public MyBinaryTreeNodeG(T data){
   this.data = data; 
  }

  public MyBinaryTreeNodeG<T> addChild(T data){
    if (data.compareTo(this.data) <= 0) {
      //left node stuff
    } else { 
     //right node stuff
    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [javadoc of Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) : `compareTo(T)` is provided by the `Comparable` interface. This method allows to compare a object instance of `T` class implementing this interface with another `T` instance. In your first example, you're comparing a `Comparable<T>` with a `Comparable<T>` (and not with `T`)

This should work :

```
public class MyBinaryTreeNodeG<T> {

    Comparable<T> data;

    // ...

    public MyBinaryTreeNodeG<T> addChild(final T data) {
        if (this.data.compareTo(data) <= 0) {
        } else {
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If something is `Comparable<T>`, it is comparable to a `T`, not comparable to a `Comparable<T>`. That's why the second snippet works.