# Java Generics in a Binary Tree, incompatible types error

Tags: java, generics, tree

I'm trying to implement a Binary Tree in java with Generics, i searched and i find this question: [Implementing Binary Tree in Java with Generic Comparable<T> data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27155596/implementing-binary-tree-in-java-with-generic-comparablet-data), but i couldn't resolve my doubts. So i have two classes,

```
BST_Tree<T>
```

and

```
Node<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

I want that my implementation can:

1. Take every type of Object and put it inside the field `key` in Node
2. Compare every node with the `key` field

This is the code:

```
public class Node < T extends Comparable < T >> {

    private T key;
    private Node left;
    private Node right;
    private Node p;

    public void setKey(T key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public T getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public Node getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public Node getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    public void setLeft(Node left) {
        this.left = left;
    }

    public void setRight(Node right) {
        this.right = right;
    }

    public void setP(Node p) {
        this.p = p;
    }

    public boolean getBolCompMin(T key) {
        return this.key.compareTo(key) < 0;
    }
}
```

My Node class is suppose to extend `Comparable` in order to compare the key.

This is my tree:

```
public class BST_Tree < T > {

    private ArrayList < Node > nodes;
    private Node root;

    public BST_Tree(Node root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    public void insertNode(T key) {
        Node z = new Node();
        z.setKey(key);
        Node x = this.root;
        Node y = new Node();

        while (x != null) {

            y = x;
            if (z.getBolCompMin(x.getKey())) {
                x = x.getLeft();
            } else {
                x = x.getRight();
            }
        }

        z.setP(y);

        if (z.getBolCompMin(y.getKey())) {
            y.setLeft(z);
        } else {

            y.setRight(z);
        }
    }
    public void InOderWalk(Node x) {
        if (x != null) {
            InOderWalk(x.getLeft());
            System.out.println(x.getKey());
            InOderWalk(x.getRight());
        }
    }

    public Node getRoot() {
        return root;
    }
}
```

My tree tries to set the key in node z but it fails. This is the error:

> incompatible types: T cannot be converted to java.lang.Comparable

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `BST_Tree` = `BinarySearchTree_Tree`

Comment: for best results use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

Comment: can i ask you why? Thank you by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
public class BST_Tree<T>
```

should be

```
public class BST_Tree<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

And every `Node` variable inside your `BST_Tree` and `Node` classes should be `Node<T>`.

This would ensure that you can only instantiate your `BST_Tree` class with element types that implement `Comparable`.

Comment: what about the method getBolCompMin(T key) that is in Node and, of course, can works only if Node extends comparable. By the way that method return true if a key is minor of the currenct Node's key (this.key)

Comment: @Francesco I still don't understand what you asked in your comment. `getBolCompMin` looks fine to me.

Comment: ok, it can work only if Node extends Comparable since it uses a method in Comparable (.compareTo)

Comment: @Francesco You mean it can work only if `T` implements `Comparable<T>`, which it does.

Comment: so you mean that booth my class have to implements Comparable<T>?

Comment: @Francesco No, neither of them has to implement Comparable. Only the type parameter T has to implement it. For example, `BST_Tree<String>` will work, since `String` implements Comparable.